# Can't end continued fraction

Tags: continued-fractions

I've done the bottom part, and don't know how to end/continue.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hI8SD.jpg

> $$5 - 3\cdot\cfrac{3}{6 - \cfrac{-3}{7}}$$

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
5 - 3 * (3 / (6 - (-3 / 7))) = 5 - 3 * (3 / (45 / 7))
                             = 5 - 3 * ((3 * 7) / 45)
                             = 5 - 3 * (7 / 15)
                             = 5 - 7 / (15 / 3)
                             = 5 - 7 / 5
                             = 25 / 5 - 7 / 5
                             = 18 / 5 (or 3 3/5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\frac{3}{45/7} = 3 \cdot \frac{7}{45}$. You can see that the above follows by multiplying both the numerator and the denominator of $\frac{3}{45/7}$ by $\frac{7}{45}$.